# How to execute jquery plugin inside a Modal window?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, plugins, modal-dialog

I am using the [Jeditable plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to edit in place. If I use it directly on the page, the plugin works perfectly; but if I use it in the modal window, it does not work anymore. The data populating the modal comes from a PHP file via AJAX, it seems that the plugin does not load in the modal.

This is the code that ajax receives from PHP:

```
<div class='edit2' id='div_1'>Dolor</div>
```

And this is the plugin call that I make:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit2').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
});
```

If i do this directly on the page, it works fine; but not in the modal.

Comment: We're going to need more information in order to help you. Show us your code, and let us know exactly which plugin you're using

Comment: thats the pugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

thats the data that cames from php file to the modal
print "<div class='edit2' id='div_1'>Dolor</div>";

and this is the code for the plugin
$('.edit2').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');

Comment: I formatted the question and corrected some minor mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

From the description and the code in the question, it looks like the problem is the time in which you call the `editable()` function.

Right now, you call it when the document is ready (inside the `$(document).ready()` function). This is fine and will work great if the element with class `.edit2` is already in the page (e.g.: when you use it directly on the page), but it doesn't work if the element is not there yet (e.g.: when you load it later using AJAX).

The solution to this issue would be to move the call:

```
 $('.edit2').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
```

from the page load into the `success` function of the AJAX call, right after you have added the content into the modal. That way, `.edit2` will exist when the plugin is called, and it should work normally.